# Is there a Relationship between the Final Fantasy games?

Tags: final-fantasy-series

I'm currently replaying Final Fantasy VII and I wondered if there was a relationship between the whole Final Fantasy Franchise before VII. I have never played any Final Fantasy but VII and XIII now. Is there a relation between Final Fantasy I,II,III,IV,V,VI and VII? And between this ones and VIII,IX,X? XI is online, so I won't bother trying it, same as XIV.

I've looked around some website, but they do not seem to mention anything like a relation between them.

Can anyone help me solve my doubt?

Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems pretty on-topic according to the FAQ under `Plot and characters in games`

Comment: See also _[What ties the various Final Fantasy series together, aside from the name?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16022/what-ties-the-various-final-fantasy-series-together-aside-from-the-name)_ on scifi.se. (It's closed, but only because scifi.se still has "general reference" closing...)

Comment: looks like you have the wrong answer accepted there, buddy
in case it's not obvious, I'm referring to danRhul's answer

Comment: @warsong - Which answer to accept is entirely up to the question asker.

Comment: @JasonBerkan obviously, but I was trying to bring attention to the fact that the accepted answer was clearly inaccurate in light of the newer answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Strictly speaking, **NO**, there is no explicit continuity within the Final Fantasy series, except where explicitly noted. (I.E. 12 inhabits the same world as Tactics IIRC, and of course, direct sequels like X-2.)

However, the series does employ many similar themes throughout, in addition to a relatively static (though ever growing!) stable of monsters, summoned monsters and spell types. In-game cosmology, while also variable is often similar. Additionally, the writers make an effort to ensure that certain 'recurring characters' (in name only), such as Cid, Biggs, and others show up in most, if not all games of the series.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It was stated by one of the directors in an interview that there was a direct connection between FF7 and FF10

Comment: I've heard the "there was an interview" rumor several times but never seen the interview. It's not very plausible without the interview itself.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Maybe if you actually tried finding the interview (first result in google) then you would be able to comment on plausability. You can find the translation of said interview here: http://uk.faqs.ign.com/articles/698/698416p1.html

Comment: @danRhul I said there is no *explicit continuity*. Which is correct. I did say 'except where explicitly noted', and referred to the specific example of 12 & Tactics, which is an analogous situation to the comment in the interview you've linked. As for the other examples you cite: quite frankly, I'm not interested in the sort of extracanonical guessing games and speculation required to accept those connections as anything more than a combination of coincidences and post-hoc easter eggs.

Comment: Regardless, the key takeaway for anyone asking this question is generally: **No, there is no continuing narrative. Start anywhere in the series, you aren't going to miss out on any sort of relevant backstory or notable connections, because *there aren't any.***

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Fair enough. For reference, only Cid shows up in all, B&W are most.

Comment: Cid was not in the original NES version of *Final Fantasy*, but was retconned into later re-releases.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Is a shame they had to retrospectively add him in. But then I guess, they didn't have much idea that there'd be more than one final fantasy.

Comment: @jumping_code they called it "Final" for a reason...

Answer (score 25):

Whilst there isn't an explicit relationship between every single Final Fantasy game in the series. Many are linked to each other:

- **Final Fantasy II & Final Fantasy IV**: In FFII there is a young boy called `Kain` who is the son of `Ricard Highwind`. He wants to one day become a dragoon. In FFIV, one of the main characters is `Kain Highwind`. Obviously, this could just be a coincidence **BUT** in the DS version of FFIV he also mentions that his father was called Ricard and he died fighting an evil empire. Moreover, in a Japanese guide for FF4 its mentioned that Cecil's `Deathbringer` once belonged to a dark knight called `Leonhart` who was indeed, a character in FFII. They also both have a town called Mysidia which is full of lovely little mages.
- **Final Fantasy IV & Final Fantasy VI**:

  > General evidence to support this largely includes the Ancient Castle. In Final Fantasy IV, Baron houses a secret chamber in the right tower where Odin is fought after he is struck down by Kainazzo. In Final Fantasy VI, Odin is petrified by a nameless sorcerer, and a hidden passage in the left wing of the castle leads to a chamber where he can be upgraded into Raiden. The same passage also contains the Blue Dragon - although the identity of Odin's opponent is not revealed, if it were the Blue Dragon that defeated him, this would place the story of his defeat in direct parallel to his death at the hands of Kainazzo. In addition the architecture of the two is similar.
  >
  > The world maps of the two games also share many similarities. Baron Castle is located where Figaro Castle would be, which fits the location of the Ancient Castle lying under Figaro's burrowing route. Doma Castle is in the north-east of the world like Fabul, and both are connected to the main continent by a narrow chain of land. Mt. Crescent lies where a chain of islands exist in Final Fantasy IV - if there was a flood, the mountain range would become a chain of small islands. Mt. Ordeals also stands in roughly the same location as the Cave to the Sealed Gate, and if the Warring Triad are somehow Lunarian in origin as mentioned above, it would make sense for Mt. Ordeals to be in the location of the Cave to the Sealed Gate, as it houses the spirit of KluYa and also is near the resting place of the Lunar Whale.
- **Final Fantasy VII and Final Fantasy X/X-2**: This is my favourite connection because I never realised it at the time, even having played them in chronological order. This connection was also explicitly told by one of the game's directors (Kietse I think). When you go to the Farplane, there is an Al Bhed boy called `Shinra` who talks about harnessing the energy of the farplane (much like Shinra using the lifestream). Although the connection is confirmed, how the connection plays out isn't. It's assumed that Shinra harnesses the energy and migrates to another world (being that Spira and Gaia are separate worlds), they are the `Cetra` from FF7.

  > Note: Interviews with scenario writer Kazushige Nojima and producer Yoshinori Kitase in the Final Fantasy X Ultimania Ω and Final Fantasy X-2 Ultimania guidebooks, have revealed that Final Fantasy VII and Final Fantasy X-2 share a plot-related connection, in which the Shin-Ra corporation in Final Fantasy VII is founded by descendants of Shinra of the Gullwings in Final Fantasy X-2.

  Specific quote: Nojima (scenario writer for FF7, FFX & FFX-2)

  > "Actually, it does. After quitting the Gullwings, Shinra received enormous
  >   financial support from Rin, and began trying to use Vegnagun to siphon Mako
  >   Energy from the Farplane. But, he is unable to complete the system for
  >   utilizing this energy in his generation, and in the future, when traveling to
  >   distant planets becomes possible, the Shin-Ra Company is founded on another
  >   world. That would happen about 1000 years after
  >   this story."

**There are many more inter game connections, but many aren't confirmed. You can find a list [here](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Inter-Game_Connections)**

Comment: The "maps look similar" argument has never been very strong. Out of game, distributing a plot-appropriate number of blobs on a square so as not to cross an edge gives a very small number of possibilties. In-game there is also no explanation why every culture would privilege the same map center points.

Comment: The link between FF7 and FFX also relies on a character from FFX2 which hadn't even been conceived of before finishing FFX's script. So if the worlds are the same, it's a very post-hoc decision.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig The world's aren't the same. The universe is. As confirmed by writer and producer. I agree though about the map looks similar argument. I'd say most of them are very similar, which is why I chose not to include it in the answer.

Comment: The royal line also has some continuity, the name Cid shows up many times throughout the series (especially in Final Fantasy IX).

Comment: @Confuzzledmaniac I think Cid is actually the only character to appear in every game.

Comment: Any reason for drive by downvotes?

Comment: I would add that the Gilgamesh appearing in FFV, VI Advance, and VIII is exactly the same Gilgamesh - which started traveling between dimensions. The authors confirmed this detail :)

Answer (score 2):

[LessPop_MoreFizz answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/76067/168029) is correct. Each Final Fantasy is separate, even if they share some common points.

I would only add an exception: Dissidia and Dissidia Duo Decim.

Both Dissidia games link all universes in one big war between Light and Darkness. Each Final Fantasy game could be interpreted as one battle among many, where Dissidia is the epic conclusion of the war.

Answer (score -3):

in ff9 zidane and garrent do a play that is the story of ff6 because the play is about a girl who is not normal and the evil emperor wants to take control her for her power and find out where is she from and so then this guy and his comrades fight the emperors army to save her.

Comment: also Zidane said Lockes name

Answer (score -4):

Based on the hints in game and how the creators tend to talk about the entire Final Fantasy series.

I see them as a big connection of stories told in a universe that goes through rebirth. It's all in the same universe, but at different points in time. Rebirth of the world is mentioned in a few games, and recurring things in each game sort of support the image of it that the games create.

It's vague but it's the part that has made me like Final Fantasy.

Comment: This is pure speculation.  You're not pointing at anything to corroborate your view.  Do you have any evidence that this is what's happening?

Answer (score -5):

I noticed while playing FF VIII that that are small similarities in the map, tiny in fact as if to think of how our continents moved apart, although the land mass and environment are completely different to most similarities except possibly the cactuar island the south east of the map.

I've played  FF VII, VIII, X AND X-2, and in some small way I've seen a story almost going backwards 1000 years at a time. I haven't done much research into it and haven't played the previous games or later games, sure the theory of different worlds is probably the most politically correct, maybe I'm just too much of a fan and forcing myself to see coincidence as something else.